# Temp storage in Apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm setting up spark cluster of 10 nodes.

spark creates `temp files` while running spark job. Does it creates temp files for all worker nodes in `master node` or on resp worker nodes ?

what will be the path for that temp directory ? Where do we set that path ?

Secondly, If that `temp dir` path gets filled, surely it will throw an error while storing more. How can I delete those temp files while running spark job itself to avoid this error ? Setting `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled` to `true` will work ?

Answer (score 1):

[Spark Doc to set temp dir](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

`spark.local.dir` can be use

> Directory to use for "scratch" space in Spark, including map output files and RDDs that get stored on disk. This should be on a fast, local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of multiple directories on different disks. NOTE: In Spark 1.0 and later this will be overridden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone), MESOS_SANDBOX (Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager.

[Spark Docs for temp dir clean up configs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts)

- `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled`, default value is `false`, Enable periodic cleanup of worker / application directories. Note that this only affects standalone mode, as YARN works differently. Only the directories of stopped applications are cleaned up.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.interval`, default is 1800, i.e. 30 minutes, Controls the interval, in seconds, at which the worker cleans up old application work dirs on the local machine.
- `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl`, default is 7*24*3600 (7 days), The number of seconds to retain application work directories on each worker. This is a Time To Live and should depend on the amount of available disk space you have. Application logs and jars are downloaded to each application work dir. Over time, the work dirs can quickly fill up disk space, especially if you run jobs very frequently.

Comment: Where all these temps will be stored ? In master node or on resp worker nodes ?

Comment: Respective worker node's disk + Master node's persistent disk

Comment: what's a significance of using both ?

Comment: Ever worker store the intermittent results on to disk for mostly checkpoint purpose if in case any goes wrong the job is tried from previous checkpoint not from the start . Same of Master it saves the results returned from Worker nodes @LennyMarshal

Comment: are you sure spark.local.dir will work for 2x versions ?

Comment: docs says " In Spark 1.0 and later this will be overridden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone), MESOS_SANDBOX (Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager."

Comment: It works on my local `SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).config("spark.local.dir","/temp/spark").getOrCreate()` I think for cluster level Spark expects it to be higher level as environment vairable if they are set else it will take the `spark.local.dir` value.  @LennyMarshal